# Break encryption by applying accidental-overwrite techniques

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, data-recovery

I read that there are ways, at least on mechanical drives, to sometimes recover data that was overwritten (not just deleted).

Now I was wondering if it was theoretically possible to break a fresh encryption of a partition that already held data (so no wiping or anything done) by applying the same (probably expensive) approach - treating the encryption as an accidental overwrite.

I'm only using encryption to protect my self against losing my notebook, not to protect my data against dedicated experts with lots of funds at their disposal (they'll just steal my passphrase anyway), but I was just wondering if the described way is feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one has ever actually demonstrated successful recovery of overwritten data on  a modern hard drive. It's an urban legend stemming from the days of hard drives with capacities orders of magnitude lower, which had enough inefficiency in their data storage that it was potentially an issue. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_recovery#Overwritten_data) and its references.

Comment: I believe some universities have actually demonstrated recovering overwritten data, but it required something similar to an atomic force microscope, and it took them thousands of dollars to recover a few bits. I think they said something like, with significant improvements, a kilobyte of recovered data could be made as cheap as a million dollars, or something insane along those lines. I don't have a citation handy though.

Comment: @forest Your belief is incorrect. Here's a paper from someone who actually tried it: https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2009/01/15/overwriting-hard-drive-data/

You've got a decent chance of retrieving a single bit of data, but no more than that.

Comment: That link regards MFM hard drives. Modern hard drive technology has changed significantly. I don't think the caveats mentioned there apply at all.

Comment: @forest I'd like to see info about that if you have it :)